# Module not found: Can't resolve 'next/font/google/target.css

Tags: css, node.js, next.js

I installed **Next.js 14.0.1** in **Node.Js v20.9.0** and **ubuntu 20.04** . The program gives an error at the very beginning.

```
Failed to compile
/var/www/html/C#/nextApp/app/layout.js

Module not found: Can't resolve 'next/font/google/target.css?{"path":"app/layout.js","import":"Inter","arguments":[{"subsets":["latin"]}],"variableName":"inter"}'
```

I removed `node_modules` folder once and reinstalled modules by running `npm i`. Of course I know **next/font** has been built into Next.js. There is path *next/font/google/target.css* in node_modules but target.css file is empty.

What is wrong with my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what's the problem and any errors that happen in the first.
My project path of was "/var/www/html/**C#**/nextApp". While better be this:
"/var/www/html/**Csharp**/nextApp". Apparently, it is sensitive to symptoms. I found this problem from **_document.js** in ".next/server/pages/".